# OS X - Adding scrollview inside window

Tags: macos

I've a nib contains a scrollview and i want to add it to my main document window in a document based Mac OS X application, considering the the scroll-view have to fill the parent by adding (top, bottom, leading and trailing) constraints, while resizing the window i want the scroll bars to appear and disappear relative to scrollview content size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the "Automatically Hide Scroller" option in the NSScrollView settings, in interface builder. It should show scroll bars only if document bigger than the ScrollView.